# Tracing the root cause of low memory warnings

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, analytics, instruments

I see a lot of low memory warnings being issued when running my application in Instruments. The total memory allocation does not exceed 5.02 MB. What could be the reason? I checked the Leak Instrument as well. There I see leaks, but due to some framework classes. None are beacause of my project classes. How to trace the root cause?

Please see attached snapshots of Leaks & Allocation instruments:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Some versions of the OS on some iOS devices will send memory warnings to the foreground app when a background app (Mail, Messages, Music player, etc.) needs sufficiently more memory.  This has nothing to do with the amount of memory your app is using.  If your app is not using a lot of memory (well under 10MB), it can usually ignore these memory warnings, as the OS will usually kill a background app that is using more memory than your app instead of your app (no guarantee though, whether your app frees memory or not!).

If you want to avoid all these memory warnings when testing, put the device in Airplane mode and force quit all the background-aware apps in the multi-tasking bar before running your app.